# How to to fuzzy merge items from a list that repeat many times python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a one column df called ```logos''' consisting of the following list:
(note I have searched for similar questions on stackoverflow to no avail

```
logos

['DEN.png',
 'MIN.png',
 'LA.png',
 'NE.png',
 'ARI.png',
 'TEN.png']
```

I would like to merge with the following df that consists of each item, minus the .png filename

```
0   ARI
1   ARI
2   ARI
3   DEN
4   DEN
5   DEN
```

I would like to merge in a way that the item from the list matches accordingly every time each team is listed in the df

```
0   ARI ARI.png
1   ARI ARI.png
2   ARI ARI.png
3   DEN DEN.png
4   DEN DEN.png
5   DEN DEN.png
```

I am wondering how I should go about this considering the `ARI` and `ARI.png` aren't identical, and item in the df I would like to merge with is listed multiple times. Is there such thing as a fuzzy join in python like in R? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is it critical to have an additional column in df? How will you use this df later on in your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFIK there is no option for 'fuzzy' merge. You can make a new column in logos with

```
logos['no_ext'] = logos.column_name.str.split('.').str.get(0)
```

and then merge with df

```
df = df.merge(logos, how='left', left_on='column_name', right_on='no_ext')
```

*Edit*

Pay atention to the `how` parameter in merge. If ommited it will default to inner. Then if you encounter a row in df that has no corresponding filename in logos it will be excluded from the merged result.

Comment: I have not used `pd.merge_ordered()` but it looks like it could have that fuzzy behavior you look for   https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_ordered.html#pandas.merge_ordered